# NodeJS, Webpack and Dockerfile in different environments

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack

I understand that as a good practice I should not pass environment variables in the Dockerfile. However I am passing/using the `NODE_ENV` variable in the Dockerfile, because I use with Webpack to build the urls in each environment.

```
# build environment
FROM node:12.10.0-alpine as build
ARG NODE_ENV
RUN apk add --update \
    python \
    python-dev \
    py-pip \
    build-base \
    git \
    openssh-client \
  && pip install virtualenv \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

# deploy environment
FROM nginx:1.17.3-alpine
ARG PORT
ENV PORT=${PORT:-9002}
EXPOSE $PORT
COPY --from=build /app/public /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Other good practice I am trying to follow in the `package.json`, is not to add dev dependencies in the general dependencies.

The problem I am facing, is that when I try to build the docker image, I do not have the required dependencies, or I will put `devDependencies` in the `dependencies`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `NODE_ENV=production` will stop `devDependencies` from getting installed. [More Info](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6803#issuecomment-64837241)

You can modify npm install command to install devDependencies:

```
npm --production=false install
```